# Displaying Arabic Text in J2me Using Eclipse

Tags: java, java-me

I am new to J2me, kindly can anybody tell me how can I do below in J2me?

```
String salam="اَللّٰهُمَّ اِنِّىْ اَسْئَلُكَ رِزْقًاوَّاسِعًاطَيِّبًامِنْ رِزْقِكَ";
byte[] bytes = salam.getBytes("UTF-8");
str1=new String(bytes);
System.out.println("Arabic :"+str1);
```

it is displaying Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… char like that

I am using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1.

Comment: If you don't use the same character set for decoding as encoding, you are not going to get the same string in this case.  What do you get if the decoding is also `"UTF-8"` ?

Comment: @Mat Not possible duplicate, but *exact* duplicate; this time, however, he provides code for us.

Comment: i have delete the perivious one

Comment: Ù„Ù„Ù‘Ù°Ù‡Ù?Ù…ÙŽÙ‘ Ø§Ù?Ù†Ù?Ù‘Ù‰Ù’ Ø§ÙŽØ³Ù’Ø¦ÙŽÙ„Ù?ÙƒÙŽ Ø±Ù?Ø²Ù’Ù‚Ù‹Ø§ÙˆÙŽÙ‘Ø§Ø³Ù?Ø¹Ù‹Ø§Ø·ÙŽÙŠÙ?Ù‘Ø¨Ù‹Ø§Ù…Ù?Ù†Ù’ Ø±Ù?Ø²Ù’Ù‚Ù? This is what i am getting Any Solution.

Comment: str1=new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); will give ?????? ??????? ?????????? ???????????????????????????? ??????

Comment: @user1029637 It is not a good idea to store localized string in java code. What about internationalization? You can read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code can be use for displaying arabic text in J2ME

```
String s=new String("\u0628\u06A9".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

where `\u0628\u06A9` is the unicode of two arabic letters

Answer (score 2):

You should use the a String contructor that allows you to specify the charset with an argument like <s>`String(byte[], Charset)`</s> *(No `Charset` in J2ME)* or [`String(byte[], String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29). Otherwise the byte array will be decoded using the platform default which may not be UTF-8.

Example:

```
 byte[] utf8bytes = ... //Byte array containing UTF-8 as bytes.
 String string = new String(utf8bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: i use it like that str1=new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); same happen ??

Comment: It is possible that what ever console you are using that is displaying System.out does not have glyphs for those code points. What happens if you try to System.out your original String literal?

Comment: there's no constructor with Charset in [J2ME MIDP String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution :
`Window > Preferences > General > Content Types`

Chose the type of file you want (Text=> java in your case )

Now paste UTF-8 to Default encoding and click "update".