# Print arabic string in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to display arabic text in java but it shows junk characters(Example : ¤[ïß¯[î) or sometimes only question marks when i print. How do i make it to print arabic. I heard that its something related to unicode and UTF-8. This is the first time i'm working with languages so no idea. I'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE.

EDIT:
If i use UTF-8 encoding then "¤[ïß¯[î" characters are becoming "????????" characters.

Comment: Do you want to print in desktop application or web application ?

Comment: where do zou print your uotput? Into eclipse console? beware, that standard command lines does not suport unicode.

Comment: The Eclipse console is just capturing the output of a process which *is* Unicode, Hurda.

Comment: @Hurda : You are right. Any alternatives so that i can print it on console or just to make sure that the output i get is right!

Comment: @Joey yes the output is unicode, but if you run this app in environment that does not support unicode you have a problem. Eclipse console is unicode capable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters you could take a look [here](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/eclipse/eclipse_quickguide_display_unicode_in_console.html). This should allow you to make Eclipse print unicode in its console (which I do not know if it is something which Eclipse supports out of the box without any extra tweaks)

If that does not solve your problem you most likely have an issue with the encoding your program is using, so you might want to create strings in some manner similar to this:

`String str = new String("تعطي يونيكود رقما فريدا لكل حرف".getBytes(), "UTF-8");`

This at least works for me.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah: Did you try them both? Also, to what exactly are you trying to print? The method above worked for me in console and `JFrame`.

Comment: `.getBytes()` uses the platform default encoding, which is essentially a random value. Converting the string to bytes and then back again is entirely redundant if the encodings match, and corrupts the string if they don't.

Answer (score 2):

If you embed the text literally in the code make sure you set the encoding for your project correctly.

Comment: No, the output comes from a webservice call

Comment: In that case you should use the correct encoding to read from the webservice response.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Java SE, Java EE, or Java ME?
If this is for Java ME, you have to make custom GlyphUtils if you use LWUIT.
Download this file:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55295133/U0600.pdf
Look list of unicode encoding..
And look at this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172732/1061371
in the answer (post) of Mohamed Nazar that edited by bernama Alex Kliuchnikau, 
 "The below code can be use for displaying arabic text in J2ME `String s=new String("\u0628\u06A9".getBytes(), "UTF-8");` where `\u0628\u06A9` is the unicode of two arabic letters" 
Look at U0600.pdf file, so we can see that Mohamed Nazar  and Alex Kliuchnikau give example to create "ba" and "kaf" character in arabic.

Then the last point that you must consider is: "Make sure your UI support unicode(I mean arabic) character."
Like LWUIT not support yet unicode (I mean arabic) character.
You should make your custom code if you mean your app is using LWUIT.