# how to read and write in arabic in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding, console

I have written this code in eclipse to get some arabic words and then print them

```
    public class getString {          
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"); 
            char[] str ;
            str= new char[10];
            r.read(str);
            out.println(str);

    }
    }
```

but the output is this:

شیرین

Ø´ÛŒØ±ÛŒÙ†

any help??

thanks in advance for your attention

Comment: Isn't `str[0]` just one character?  How do you get more than one character?

Comment: Fix the console encoding in Eclipse to be UTF-8. If you are on Windows it's not going to work.

Comment: WHat happens if you read from System.in and write to System.out without trying to change the encoding?

Comment: @bmargulies: please don't confuse Eclipse console with Windows command console (cmd.exe).

Comment: @PeterLawrey sry It was a problem in typing

Comment: @bmargulies I have tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, what's your operating system, pace @BalusC.

Comment: try that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682292/print-arabic-string-in-java

Comment: I assume you really mean the Eclipse console, not build in Eclipse, and run from command line :-) If it is Eclipse all the way, add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclipse.ini

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set workspace encoding to UTF-8 by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*. This also affects the encoding of the stdout in Eclipse console.

[image]

Then you can also just replace `new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8")` by `System.out`.

Comment: Then your problem is caused elsewhere not visible in the information provided so far. It works for me. Perhaps you need to create a new Run configuration so that the change in encoding is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this setup:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8"));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));

String input = in.readLine();
out.write(input);
out.write("\n");
out.flush();
```

This is how I used to create IO to handle non-latin characters. Note that this has no auto-flush.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using windows, then this is how you set encoding as UTF 8 in eclipse:

1- Open Run Dialog > select "your java application" > Common Tab >
    Encoding > Other > "set it to UTF-8"

[image]

2- Open Run Dialog > select "your java application" > Arguments Tab > VM Arguments > Add "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

[image]

3- Open **Window** Menu > General > Workspace > Text file encoding
    should be set to "UTF-8"

[image]

Then you can run your application.

Comment: Can you go to **Edit > Set Encoding, then choose UTF-8**, then make a new test?